# Auto rename multiple sheets and copy content of main to all newly created sheets

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have a master sheet that contains formatted columns (B2:Y14 and A18:B24) and am trying to create as many sheets as there are in the forthcoming month and then copy the master sheet data into each of the newly created sheets.

For example: for the month of December I would need to create 31 sheets named DEC1...DEC31 that contain the data from the master sheet.

What I have tried is the following:

```
Sub AddSheets()
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim curSheet As String
    Dim prevSheet As String

    'Dim summarySheet As Workbook

    newName = Application.InputBox("Name", "Rename Sheet", "", Type:=2)
    numSheets = Application.InputBox("Range", "Number of Sheets", "", Type:=1)

    prevSheet = "Main"
    'Set summarySheet = Sheets("Main").UsedRange.Copy


    For j = 1 To numSheets
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(CStr(prevSheet))
        curSheet = newName & " " & j
        Sheets(CStr(curSheet)).Name = curSheet
        Sheets("Main").UsedRange.Copy
        Sheets(CStr(curSheet)).Select
        Sheets(CStr(curSheet)).Paste
        prevSheet = curSheet
        'ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next j
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to  set the new sheet as variable when added.  Then you can refer to it.

```
Sub AddSheets()
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim prevSheet As String
    Dim newsht As Worksheet
    'Dim summarySheet As Workbook

    newName = Application.InputBox("Name", "Rename Sheet", "", Type:=2)
    numSheets = Application.InputBox("Range", "Number of Sheets", "", Type:=1)

    prevSheet = "Main"
    'Set summarySheet = Sheets("Main").UsedRange.Copy


    For j = 1 To numSheets
        Set newsht = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(CStr(prevSheet)))
        newsht.Name = newName & " " & j
        Sheets("Main").UsedRange.Copy newsht.Range("A1")
        prevSheet = newsht.Name

    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: @user2130444 Did this help?

Comment: Thank you Scott for the very timely reply.  The solution provided worked with one small addition: I had to use newsht.Name = newName & " " & j.

Comment: @user2130444 opps, you are correct.  I will change.  Please consider marking as correct.  big green check mark by the down arrow.